# Uncaught Type error in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get the below error message when I open my html file.

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (near
'..._react2.default.createClass...')
(anonymous function)bundle.js 966
_webpack_require bundle.js 20
(anonymous function)bundle.js 73
_webpack_require bundle.js 20
(anonymous function)bundle.js 63
_webpack_require bundle.js 64
```

This is my Html code

```
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script src="js/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my app.js file
   `import firstComponent from './firstComponent'`

This is my first component.js file

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
var CommentBox=React.createClass({
 render:function(){
   return(
      <div className="CommentBox">
                HelloWorldCommentBox
      </div>
   );
   }
  });
  ReactDOM.render(
  <commentBox/>,
       document.getElementById('content')
  );
```

Please Help me with this

Comment: `commentBox` should be `CommentBox`

Comment: @Rajesh Why? I suspect the error comes from the fact `createClass` was removed in 16

Comment: @Li357 I'm not aware about that.

Comment: @Rajesh It was deprecated in 15 and officially removed, see "Packaging": https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html

Answer (score 1):

The name of the component has to started with a capital letter and you have to use use the same name when you use the component.

The component is

> `<CommentBox/>`

not

> `<commentBox/>`